# Laravel model plural table name not working

Tags: php, laravel

PHP version: 5.6.33

Laravel version: 5.2.45

I am following the "quickstart" tutorial on the Laravel website https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart.

I'm in the section "Creating The Task" https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#creating-the-task

My code looks just like the one on the website:

```
// add new task
Route::post('/task', function(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

Model looks just like the finished version as well https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic/blob/master/app/Task.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    //
}
```

So when I attempt to add a task I get the following error:

`FatalErrorException in Inflector.php line 265:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'`

When I update the model to the following it works:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tasks';
    //
}
```

But according to documentation I should not have to.

> Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the flights
>   table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Why do I have to specifically name the table in the model to make this work?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using 5.2 for new projects.  It's not maintained.  5.1 is the LTS version.

Comment: Please run `composer show doctrine/inflector` on the command line. What does the `versions` entry say?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir versions : * v1.3.0 says it requires PHP 7 but I'm not planning on updating anytime soon

Comment: You must have installed Laravel with PHP 7.1+. Did you copy the `composer.lock` file or the `vendor` directory from a different machine? What's the result of `php -v` on the command line?

Comment: Installed like this `composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.2.*" quickstart --prefer-dist`

`Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.31): Loading from cache
Created project in quickstart`

Comment: What's the result of `php -v`?

Comment: I guess you are right: `PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2018 02:59:59) ( NTS )`

Don't know how I installed that.

Comment: But how does phpinfo() return PHP 5.6.33 but `php -v` return another?

Comment: You can run different PHP versions on the command line (`php -v`) and on the web server (`phpinfo()`).

Comment: @Devon Laravel `5.5` is the latest LTS version.

Comment: @HCK but 5.5 doesn't support PHP 5.6...

Comment: @devon if you have the liberty to choose, of course you'll go for the most updated/latest version.. and PHP 5.6 is not.

Comment: Robert Rocha, are you using Apache or Nginx to run your server?

Comment: @HCK... read the question next time.  They are running PHP 5.6.  Laravel 5.1 is the only maintained version that supports it.

Comment: @hck read the comment section mate. He/she can choose an updates version. Why recommend him/her a buggy one? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Apache server .